# Bash Script looping on Find Command: output has spaces

Tags: bash, find, spaces

I have the following code which attempts to find all files which match certain patterns and copy them to a new directory, adding a suffix if the file already exists.  This is because duplicate filenames appear in the original list - as they are found in different directories.

It works as expected except fot filenames containing `spaces` which the `for in loop` takes as delimiters.

This code is from various parts of stackoverflow, which I have used and I do not fully understand.

I have tried various combinations of quoting the filename, to the extent I only copied files with spaces.

Can someone advise as to how I can resolve this problem

```
patterns=( "wom*.gif" "StarB*.gif" "logos*.gif" )
for pattern in "${patterns[@]}"
do
  for fname in $(find $source -name $pattern); 
  do
    echo Path-and-Filename: $fname
    filename=$(basename "$fname")
    extension=${filename##*.}
    filename=${filename%.*}
    echo Just-Filename: $filename.$extension
    suffix=""
    count=0
    while [ -f $dest$filename$suffix.$extension ]
    do
      count=$(($count+1))
      suffix="("$count")"
    done

    cp -v -p "$fname" $dest"$filename"$suffix.$extension >>$dest"CopyImageFiles-"$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").log 2>>$dest"CopyImageFiles-"$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").log
  done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I got it to work, using @ormaaj's idea of using a while loop for reading.  I have not worked out properly what it does, but I have now copied all my files and that is what I wanted.

I am sure it is still 'fragile' and any advice would be appreciated.

I did not use -print0 as I did not know how to read the lines of the output, it appeared as one long line.  I assume I needed to set the delimiter for each filename, but could not figure it out.  The brain is very slow nowadays.

```
patterns=( "*.gif" "*.GIF" "*.tif"  "*.TIF" "*.jpg" "*.JPG" "*.png" "*.PNG")
for pattern in "${patterns[@]}"
do
  find "/Volumes/Public/media_pics" -name "$pattern" | while IFS= read -r fname;
    do
      echo Full-Filename: "$fname"
      filename=$(basename "$fname")
      extension=${filename##*.}
      filename=${filename%.*}
      echo Just-Filename: $filename.$extension
      suffix=""
      count=0
      while [ -f $dest$filename$suffix.$extension ]
      do
        count=$(($count+1))
        suffix="("$count")"
      done

      cp -v -p "$fname" "$dest$filename$suffix.$extension" >>$dest"CopyImageFiles-"$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").log 2>>$dest"CopyImageFiles-"$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").log
  done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You have done in partially good.

`for pattern in "${pattern[@]}"` works fine, the spaces are preserved to the `pattern` variable.

`for fname in $(find $source -name $pattern);` is broken.

Keep in mind that `pattern` contains a space.

Fix it to:

```
for fname in $(find "$source" -name "$pattern");
```

**Adding quotes to the further statements is left as an exercise ;-)**

Comment: Sorry - it does not appear any different, the filenames with spaces are creating multiple entries in the `for in loop` split at the space character.

Comment: Wrong. You can't iterate over filenames this way. At least you've helped improve the odds the script doesn't fail before reaching the problem.

Comment: @mcl see the added line about the exercise ;-)

Comment: @ormaaj  I read your references and tried to implement `Don't read lines with for` but I obviously got it wrong as I got an ambiguous redirect error after searching for the matching files. I tried `while IFS= read -r aline; do echo "$aline" ; done < $(find "/Volumes/Public/media_pics" -name "*.gif")`

Comment: @mcl You want a process substitution `<(...)`, `$(...)` is a command substitution. You also probably want to follow the instructions regarding `find` with nul-delimited output (`-print0`).

Comment: @mcl beautiful solution, +1